# Unable to set or create the 'className' attribute for a newly created div

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, htmlelements

I am unable to `setAttribute()` or even `createAttribute()` to add a className to a newly created `div` element. It may be worth noting that the div is created inside of a `fetch().then()` chain using the `createElement` command. The code looks like this...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let row = 0
    fetch(domain + "/boards/new")
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(json => json.spaces)
        .then(spaces => spaces.forEach( (iRow) => {
            let col = 0
            iRow.forEach( (iCol) => {
                if (iCol != null){
                    let checker = document.createElement('div')
                    let color = iCol.team
                    let c_id = iCol.id
                    checker.createAttribute(className)
                    checker.setAttribute(className, `${color}-checker`)
                    checker.createAttribute(id)
                    checker.setAttribute(id, c_id)
                    checker.createAttribute(data-pos)
                    checker.setAttribute(data-pos, `[${row}][${col}]`)
                    document.body.appendChild(checker)
                }
                col = col + 1
            })
            row = row + 1
        }))
})
```

It gets all the way to the line `checker.createAttribute(className)` but then errors out, saying 'className is note defined' which is odd, className SHOULD be understood by the compiler as a global HTML attribute, should it not?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createAttribute

The docs mention that the parameters for the `createAttribute()` method takes in a string parameter, so it would seem that when you get the error that `className not defined`, it's because it's trying to find the String that is stored in `className`